# How to process a postgres array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, perl

I'm new at Perl. I'm trying to select an array column in a postgres view using a Perl script, but I'm unsure on how to break the scalar array as it comes into Perl into a Perl array, so that I can step through each field.

What advise can you offer?

(using postgres 9.3, relatively new Perl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;
# open database connection
my $dbh = DBI- >connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$db::DB_name;host=$db::DB_host;port=$db::DB_port","$db::DB_user","$db::DB_pwd");
if ( !defined $dbh ) {&log_print("Cannot connect to database!\n"); die"dieing...\n";} 
#fetch record from postgres database
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select progno, track_numbers from processing");
if ( !defined $sth ) {    die "Cannot prepare statement: $DBI::errstr\n";} 
$rows = $sth->execute();
my ($p_progno, $p_track_numbers) = $sth->fetchrow();
$sth->finish;
#output scalar
&log_print("$p_track_numbers\n"); 
#result: ARRAY(0x1975d38)
print Dumper($p_track_numbers);
#result:
#$VAR1 = [
#          16,
#          17,
#          18,
#          19,
#          20,
#          21,
#          22
#        ];
#? How do I step through each $p_track_numbers in a foreach?
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your example. `fetchrow` is an old alias for `fetchrow_array`, which would not return an array reference as one of its list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dereference the array reference by prepending the `@`:

```
for my $track_number (@$p_track_numbers) {
    print $track_number, "\n"
}
```